# Can not find Android-> Android device monitor option

Tags: android

I have updated android studio latest patch.Now I cannot find Android device monitor option under TOOL tab.Is there any bug with the latest patch. Need some help in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Android Device Monitor guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html), they mentioned:

> However, most components of the Android Device Monitor are deprecated
>   in favor of updated tools available in Android Studio 3.0 and higher.

and in [Android Monitor Basics guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html) they said that it's removed from Android Studio 3.0

> This tool was removed in Android Studio 3.0.  You should get the
>   latest version of Android Studio and use the new Android Profiler
>   instead.

But, you can still access the Android Device Monitor from

> $ANDROID_HOME/tools/monitor

Answer (score 1):

Android device monitor option is deprecated. Instead, use Android Profiler in Android Studio 3.0 and higher to profile your app's CPU, memory, and network usage. If you want to perform other debugging tasks, such as sending commands to a connected device to set up port-forwarding, transfer files, or take screenshots, then use the Android Debug Bridge (adb), Android Emulator, Device File Explorer, or Debugger window.